# Python pandas read_csv returning FileNotFoundError despite existing Mac

Tags: python, pandas, filenotfoundexception

I am trying to read into a pandas dataframe from a csv. The data is in the format:

```
date,total_bytes
2018-08-27,1.84E+14
2018-08-30,1.90E+14
2018-08-31,1.93E+14
```

My code looks like:

```
from pandas import read_csv
from pandas import datetime
from matplotlib import pyplot


series = 
read_csv(r'/Users/taylorjewell/Desktop/dataset_size_daily.csv', 
header=0)
print(series.head())
series.plot()
pyplot.show()
```

Despite that path existing (I have checked countless times), I am getting a file not found exception for some reason:FileNotFoundError: File b'/Users/taylorjewell/Desktop/dataset_size_daily' does not exist

I am running this on a mac if that is relevant. Any help you are able to offer would be much appreciated!!

Comment: why did you read file `dataset_size_daily.csv` but the error says `dataset_size_daily` only (without `csv`)?

Comment: In the interpreter, what do you get when your type in `r'/Users/taylorjewell/Desktop/dataset_size_daily.csv'` ?

Answer (score 1):

For file paths, I would suggest using pathlib:

```
from pathlib import Path

data_file = Path("/Users/taylorjewell/Desktop/dataset_size_daily.csv")

series = read_csv(data_file, header=0)
```

However, it also depends on where you are trying to access the file from.

Answer (score 0):

i dont think you need to use the r bit for mac
try 
read_csv('/Users/taylorjewell/Desktop/dataset_size_daily.csv', 
header=0)

Answer (score 0):

Just ran into this issue today and wanted to share-

If you download a CSV file to a mac
But then open the file and save it
The file extension changes to .numbers

So make sure you just move the file without opening it, and double-check that the file extension is .csv